# How do I classify a clean time series and a time series with too much noisy?

Tags: matlab, time-series, signals, signal-processing

I have a data set of two classes.One class is clean time series and another class is time series with too much noisy.How can I classify the two classes in Matlab?

Comment: Do you have some sample plot for us? Maybe in the time and frequency domain for both signal types.

Comment: Sorry,I don't how to show the plot in Stackoverflow.I have tried to use SNR for classification but it is useless beacause I only have the mixed signal. How do I classify them by analyzing the time domain and the frequency domain?Can you tell me more details?There are sample plot s under this [link](https://www.physionet.org/challenge/2017/) in Figure 1.